# Changing of Data format from Pivoted data in Dataframes using Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

### The Scenario

My dataset was in format as follows:

Which I refer as **ACTUAL FORMAT**

```
uid iid rat tmp
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
22  377 1   878887116
244 51  2   880606923
166 346 1   886397596
298 474 4   884182806
115 265 2   881171488
253 465 5   891628467
305 451 3   886324817
6   86  3   883603013
```

and while passing it to other function (KMeans Clustering) it requires to be format like this, which I've created using Pivot mapping:

Which I refer as **MATRIX FORMAT**

```
uid 1               2               3               4
4   4.3320762062    4.3407749532    4.3111995162    4.3411425423
5   4               3               2.1952622349    3.1913491995
6   4               3.4233243638    3.8255108621    3.948791424
7   4.4983411706    4.0477240538    4.0241460801    5
8   4.1773004578    4.0191412859    4.0442369862    4.1754642909
9   4.2733984521    4.2797130861    4.2682723131    4.2816986988
15  1               3.0554789259    3.2279546684    3.1282278957
16  5               4.3473697565    4.0675394438    5
```

### The Problem:

Now, Since I need the result / MATRIX FORMAT Data to passed again to the First Algorithm, I need to convert it to OLD FORMAT.

### Coversion:

For conversion of OLD to MATRIX Format I did:

```
Pivot_Matrix = source_data.pivot(values='rat', index='uid', columns='iid')
```

I tried reversing & interchanging of values to get the  OLD FORMAT, which has apparently failed. Is there any way to retrieve MATRIX to OLD FORMAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for columns names and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.stack().rename_axis(('uid','iid')).reset_index(name='rat')
print (df.head())
   uid iid       rat
0    4   1  4.332076
1    4   2  4.340775
2    4   3  4.311200
3    4   4  4.341143
4    5   1  4.000000
```